# Unknown Error in android studio / in log : WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I have an unknown error in android emulator and I can not use a vitual device.

[image]

[image]
I opened the idea.log and I saw :

2022-02-17 11:15:06,611 [ 161443]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:06,611 [ 161443]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:06,612 [ 161444]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:06,737 [ 161569]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
2022-02-17 11:15:11,130 [ 165962]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,131 [ 165963]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,132 [ 165964]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,133 [ 165965]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,630 [ 166462]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,631 [ 166463]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,631 [ 166463]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,632 [ 166464]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,633 [ 166465]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,633 [ 166465]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:11,634 [ 166466]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found
2022-02-17 11:15:12,656 [ 167488]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found

I note that I have uninstalled androidstudio two times but the problem have not solved yet.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing same issue. can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pathway that needs to be set (for your Android SDK).

If you are using windows then it's probably the Environment Variables (?) where the path needs to be set.

You will also do yourself a favour by having one edition of Android Studio installed (like a latest edition which is mostly connected with your Flutter settings), and deleting all the others in your download folders or anywhere else.  They will also flag flutter doctor issues that may confuse you.